# How to define a type alias for System.String^

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I´m trying to define my own type aliases as follows:

```
using PrjString = System.String;
using PrjInt = System.Int32;
using PrjFloat = System.Single;
using PrjDateTime = System.DateTime;
```

I´m facing problems with the `String` type. When I try to use the string and pass it as reference:

```
PrjString^ name;
GetName(name); // Receives name as reference and return the gathered name
```

I cannot compile:

```
PrjString ^name: error CS0118: `string` is a `type` but is used like a `variable`
```

On the other hand, If I define:

```
using PrjString = System.String^;
```

It does not compile as well:

```
using PrjString = System.String^: error CS1002: ; expected
```

Is there a way to define a type alias for `System.String^` ?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to alias the base types?

Comment: `^` is not proper syntax in c#

Comment: This is a question not exactly related to the problem, but i´m building a cross environment SDK where I need all types to be named the same between platforms....

Comment: Well using PrjString = System.String works in C#. why do you have ^ with the name

Comment: Because GetName is a C++/CLI function and will receive it by reference....

Comment: @Mendes then you should use the `ref` keyword instead like `GetName(ref name);`

Comment: `typedef System::String^ PrjString;`  The odds you'll bring this to a good end are quite remote, you can't hide C++/CLI implementation details in macros and typedefs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` notation is not valid syntax in c#. To pass by reference, use the `ref` keyword:

```
using PrjString = System.String;

PrjString name;
GetName(ref name);
```

Comment: Seens that I cannot pass String´s as reference.... [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929333/c-cli-why-cant-i-pass-strings-by-reference)

Comment: Yes, you can. You linked to a C++ answer